# TypeError: sqlDb.Connection is not a constructor in Rest Service using Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, rest

I'm building a simple REST Service with Node.js

When I send a `GET` request I'm getting an error saying:

> TypeError: sqlDb.Connection is not a constructor at Object.exports.executeSql

**Here is my code.**

**settings.js**

```
exports.dbConfig = {
  user: "sa",
  password: "sam",
  server: "localhost\\1433",
  database: "SampleDb",
  port: 1433
};
exports.webPort = 9000;
```

**db.js**

```
var sqlDb = require("mssql");
var settings = require("../settings");

exports.executeSql = function(sql, callback) {

  var conn = new sqlDb.Connection(settings.dbConfig);
  conn.connect()
  .then(function() {
    var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
    req.query(sql)
    .then(function(recordset) {
      callback(recordset);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(null, err);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(null, err);
  });
};
```

**employee.js**

```
var db = require("../core/db");
exports.getList = function(req, resp) {
  db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM emp", function(data, err) {
    if (err) {
      resp.writeHead(500, "Internal Error Occoured", {
        "Content-type": "text/html"
      });
      resp.write("<html><head><title>500</title></head><body>500: Internal Error, Details:" + err + "</body></html>");
      resp.end();
    } else {
      resp.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });
      resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    resp.end();
  });
};
```

Comment: do you mean to use `ConnectionPool`?

Comment: That worked. I am referring an old tutorial, is this a new keyword? Because in the tutorial it says to use  >Connection

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes

Comment: @JohannesMerz  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change `Connection` to `ConnectionPool`

```
 const conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(settings.dbConfig);
 conn.connect();
```

From the mssql package's npm documentation:

> 3.x to 4.x changes -
>   `Connection` was renamed to `ConnectionPool`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes

Comment: I tried with the above changes and still it throws undefined.[Can you have a look at this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847239/cypress-task-undefined-even-though-the-promise-is-returned)

Answer (score 2):

Following [this correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48033280/447356), I just had this issue now when upgrading node.js modules, but having to support the older code as well, I had to write a method that can wrong seamlessly in both cases:

```
function CreateDbConnection(callback) {
    let connectionFunc = null;
    if (sql.ConnectionPool)
        connectionFunc = sql.ConnectionPool;
    else
        connectionFunc = sql.Connection;
    let connection = new connectionFunc(settings.sqlConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('Error connecting to database: ' + (err.message || err));
            callback("ERROR", null);
        } else {
            callback(null, connection);
        }
    });
}
```

This will check what method is available and use it.

Example for actual usage:

```
CreateDbConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('connection failed');
    } else {
        console.log('Doing stuff with connection...');
        //important to close when done:
        connection.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with the changes and still it throws undefined.[Can you have a look at this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847239/cypress-task-undefined-even-though-the-promise-is-returned)

Answer (score 0):

Change `var sqlDb = require("mssql");` for  `sqlDb = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");`

and install package:

```
 npm install msnodesqlv8 --save
```

using the mssql package as well.